# how to specify the content type while creating an item in sharepint list using rest api or javascript

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript

I have to upload a link to document library using `rest api` by specifying the content type.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the `ContentTypeId` property with value in the Json data. Use Content TypeId: `0x01010A00D045D10D5906534BB9712EC3D01B4FD1` for **Link to a Document** content type.

```
var listName="<listname here>"
var itemType=getItemTypeForListName(listName);
    var data= {
                "__metadata": { "type": itemType},
                "Title": "blah blah",
                "ContentTypeId":"<ContentTypeID>"
              };
var url= "/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle("+listName+")/Items"; 
addNewItem(url,data);



function addNewItem(url, data) {
    $.ajax({
        url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + url,
        type: "POST",
        headers: {
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
            "content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose"
        },
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function (error) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(error));
        }
    });
}

// Get List Item Type metadata
function getItemTypeForListName(name) {
    return "SP.Data." + name.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + name.split(" ").join("").slice(1) + "ListItem";
}
```

Comment: thank you so much..  can you please help with adding a link document library similarly

Comment: Edited my answer with the contentype for Link to a document

Comment: i added the content type.. it says item type is not identified by the model.Please help

Comment: An unexpected 'PrimitiveValue' node was found when reading from the JSON reader. A 'StartObject' node was expected...i get this error..please help

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a `JavaScript Object Model` code to add a content type to an item, then below code can be helpful.

**Declare the global variables**

```
var contentTypeCollection = null;
var contentTypeName = "YourContentTypeName";
var contentTypeId = null;
var clientContext = null;
```

**Get the content types from a list**

Here we get the collection of associated content types in a list, and then get the ID of the one which we need to add to an item.

```
function getListContentTypes() {
    try {
        var listCollection;
        var list;
        clientContext = new SP.ClientContext("http://YourSite");
        if (clientContext != undefined && clientContext != null) {
            var web = clientContext.get_web();
            listCollection = web.get_lists();
            list = listCollection.getByTitle("YourListName");
            contentTypeCollection = list.get_contentTypes();
            clientContext.load(contentTypeCollection); 
            clientContext.executeQueryAsync(onContentTypesQuerySucceeded, queryFailure);
        }
    }
    catch (err) {
        alert("Error");
    }
}

function onContentTypesQuerySucceeded() {
    var contentTypeEnumerator = contentTypeCollection.getEnumerator();
    while (contentTypeEnumerator.moveNext()) {
        var content = contentTypeEnumerator.get_current();
        if (content.get_name() == contentTypeName) {
            contentTypeId = content.get_id().toString();
        }
    }

    // Call the function to create an item
    //
    CreateListItem(clientContext, contentTypeId);
}
```

**Create an item with content type in the list**

```
function CreateListItem(clientContext, contentTypeId) {

    // Get current web 
    //
    var oWeb = clientContext.get_web();

    // Get list by title
    //
    var oList = oWeb.get_lists().getByTitle("YourListName");

    // Create new object for list item creation 
    //
    var oListItemCreationInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();
    var newListItem = oList.addItem(oListItemCreationInfo);

    newListItem.set_item('ContentTypeId', contentTypeId);
    newListItem.update();
    clientContext.load(newListItem);
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(onSuccessAddItem, queryFailure);              
}

function onSuccessAddItem() {
    alert("Item added successfully");
}

function queryFailure() {
    alert("Error");
}
```